# How to write text to a specific line in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm wondering if there is a way to write data from the program to a specific line on an external text document.

For example, so far within my program I have a string array which gets the users input and saves it in the corresponding element and into the text file. It can read the first element fine, however how do I get it so when I enter the input for element 2 it overwrites what is on line 2 so when it reads the text file it displays the newest input into a label?

Comment: is the text document in question formatted in a particular way that would make the line easily identifiable?  Also can we see code for what you've done so far?  If it's not easily identifiable, it should be a simple for loop with a counter, if it is, then just loop through the document line by line until you run into your identifier.  Also, check the linked answers, as this question is marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simplest approach would be:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
lines[index] = newText;
File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

However, that *assumes* that there's already an appropriate number of lines in the file - is that always the case?

Note that this is also potentially inefficient in memory if the file is very large - but making it more efficient would also make the code more complicated.

Comment: That's great, thank you! Yes there is a fixed amount of lines and i'm not that worried about the memory size to be honest however I will keep that in mind for future programs, thanks again!